# Correct method to use MediaPlayer in android app

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

sorry my english, but I'm from Brazil and I used the google translator.

Well, I'm struggling in this application where I am trying to make a streaming an online radio, works fine in version 2.2, but version 4.0 does not work. No error occurs, simply does not work. Below is my code.

I appreciate any help.

```
package com.radiomiriam;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity {
public String url = "http://69.64.48.96:9880";
public MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    play();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void stop(){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finalizando...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(player.isPlaying()){
        player.stop();
    }
}

public void play(){
    if(player.isPlaying()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Já está em execução!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Preparando...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
        try {
            player.setDataSource(url);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            player.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        player.start();
    }
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    final int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
    case R.id.btnPlay:
        play();
        break;
    case R.id.btnStop:
        stop();
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Hello, excuse my insistence but I still have not found the solution to my problem and do not know how to solve, I have once again asking for your help to solve this problem.

The application runs in versions 2.x and 3.x but not in version 4.x. Below is a link to download the project, to which you can take a look and help me.

http://nsi.inf.br/RadioMiriam.rar (removed)

Comment: Try changing `e.printStackTrace();` to `Log.e("SomeTagName", e.getMessage(), e);`  and see if the errors show up in logcat.

Comment: What I put in SomeTagName?

Comment: I used the log but does not return any error in the debug, simply does not play.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i downloaded your project and it actually returns error Code:
E/MediaPlayer( 1976): error (-38, 0)

It is caused by starting mediaplayer before it is prepared.

I have made few changes and it started to work. You should :

1. Set onPrepared listener on MediaPlayer (i.e. in onCreate)

   ```
   player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
       @Override
       public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
           mp.start();
       }
   });
   ```
2. Remove player.start() from your play() method
3. Set datasource in this way (in your play() method)

   ```
   player.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("http://69.64.48.96:9880/"));
   ```

It works on my HTC Sensation with Android 4.0.3

If you need any assistance please let me know.

EDIT: i forgot, i also removed

```
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
```

It is redundant

Comment: I want to thank you. Thank you for download and test the project so far had failed to solve the problem, and now with your suggestion worked perfectly.

Thank you again.

Comment: I would like to give a vote of reputation, but I can not because I have only 14 points. But once you reach I will.

Answer (score 2):

The `prepare()` call is probably blocking the UI thread (which android 4.0 hates it when you do that)

You will need to this work in a background thread like an asynctask.  Here is a anonymous version of implementing AsyncTask to run `play()` in the background.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    final int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
    case R.id.btnPlay:
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                play();
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
        break;
    case R.id.btnStop:
        stop();
        break;
    }
}
```

You will need to read up a bit about [MediaPlayer's states](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepare%28%29)  (playing, preparing, stopped, etc) to learn why calling prepare will block the UI thread (

for more info on [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Sorry I'm beginner in this language and do not understand how to adapt it to my code, can you help me? I'm here with doubts "protected Void doInBackground (Void. .. voids) {".

Excuse the ignorance

Comment: @EdersondosSantos  check out this article/doc on [asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Sorry I did not really understand how to use AsyncTask, please help me to adapt it in my code, you need to see other files for this?

Please I'm two days in search of a solution and AsyncTask seems to be the right solution, but I tried many times without success.

Comment: Don't do this, use prepareAsync

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set any link between buttons in your .xml file and your code. onClick method is never called even though you are pressing the buttons.

Replace your onCreate method with this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    playButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    play();
}
```

Comment: Actually the buttons work, I made the connection through the tag android: onclick = "onClick" in xml layout

Answer (score 0):

It is always better in android to do any **IO** work on a background thread.

And that includes MediaPlayer . but in MediaPlayer case you already have `prepareAsync()` method to prepare the MediaPlayer in the background for you.

A good way to do that is like this:

```
package com.radiomiriam;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity  implements OnPreparedListener{
public String url = "http://69.64.48.96:9880";
public MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    play();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void stop(){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finalizando...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(player.isPlaying()){
        player.stop();
    }
}

public void play(){
    if(player.isPlaying()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "J? est? em execuç?o!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Preparando...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
        try {
            player.setDataSource(url);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            player.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mp.start();
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    final int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
    case R.id.btnPlay:
        play();
        break;
    case R.id.btnStop:
        stop();
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Also it is always a good practice to read the documentations, so here is a link to MediaPlayer API : [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Comment: Hello Mr.Me , I tried your code, but unfortunately it did not work well.

I really do not know what is happening.