# Play dynamic MP3 files in MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I need to play local mp3 from the RAW folder. When i am calling it with direct name, like this way it works fine:

```
final MediaPlayer mP = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound);
mP.start();
```

But i cannot figure it out how to play mp3 according to a variable containing the name of mp3, for example:

```
String filemane = "my.mp3";
final MediaPlayer mP = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.filemane);
mP.start();
```

I understand this doesn't work since in the raw folder there is no file "filemane.mp3"

Please point me how to play "my.mp3"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct method to use MediaPlayer in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032590/correct-method-to-use-mediaplayer-in-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Uri` as the second parameter.

```
MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, Uri.fromFile(new File(path)));
```